# Spacing agents in NetLogo based on territory size

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to develop a model in NetLogo in which animal agents will be randomly distributed across space each time the model is started.  However, the animals are territorial.  Any suggestions on how to have the animals start with a circular territory of some size that can overlap with other animals to a certain extent but not completely?  Below is the fragment of code I have started on it, but frankly I don't even know where to start.  In the code below the animals aren't aware of the other territories when initialized.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
to setup  
    ask n-of (number-of-animals) TropForst 
    sprout-animals 1
    set territory patches in-radius ((sqrt ((territory-animals * 1000000)/ pi)) / 10)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one way to do it :
you can change the center patch for each type of animals and you can set how much you want their territory to overlap.

```
breed [animals animal]
animals-own [territory]
to setup  
  clear-all
    create-animals number-of-animals / 2  
    [
      set color red
    set territory pathces-in-territory patch 10 10
      move-to one-of territory 
      ]


   create-animals number-of-animals / 2  
    [
      set color blue

      set territory pathces-in-territory patch 15 15 
      move-to one-of territory 
      ]


end

to-report pathces-in-territory [Center ]
  let ptr []
  ask Center [set ptr patches in-radius 5]
  report ptr
end
```

[image]

you can do it this way as well:

```
breed [animals animal]
animals-own [territory]
to setup  
  clear-all
    create-animals number-of-animals / 2  
    [
      set color red
    set territory pathces-in-territory patch 10 10 5
      move-to one-of territory 
      ]


   create-animals number-of-animals / 2  
    [
      set color blue

      set territory pathces-in-territory patch 15 15 10
      move-to one-of territory 
      ]


end

to-report pathces-in-territory [Center rd]
  let ptr []
  ask Center [set ptr patches in-radius rd]
  report ptr
end
```

[image]

since I like examples ;) this is another one which you can change the pcolor of each territory as well :

```
to-report pathces-in-territory [Center rd c]
  let ptr []
  ask Center [set ptr patches in-radius rd 
    ask  patches in-radius rd [set pcolor c]
    ]
  report ptr
end
```

[image]

and you can call the function like this : `set territory pathces-in-territory patch 10 6 15 blue`
***Update**

I should check it with netlogo later

```
create-animals number-of-animals  
        [
          set color blue
          move-to one-of patches with [not any? animals-here]
          set territory patches in-radius 5 

          ]
```

In case you want the territory to be defined for each individual animal you can check if there is no turtle in radius more that the territory for example 5 and then set the territory to patches around the turtle

```
   create-animals number-of-animals / 2  
    [

      move-to one-of patches with [not any? animals in-radius 5]
      set territory pathces-in-territory patch-here 2
      let h who
      ask territory [set pcolor h + 10 ] ; just for visual clarification 
      move-to one-of territory 
      ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great!  I'm still trying to figure out exactly what is happening.  But, if I'm reading it correctly, a territory includes multiple animals?  Is it also possible for each single animal to have an independent territory?  Sorry if that is obvious.  Thanks again!

Comment: I was not sure if you need a territory for a type of animals or each individual , the one I used is a territory for each type not individual, but you can change that too

Comment: Thanks!  So I would `ask animals` first then assign a territory?

Comment: I dont have access to netlogo now to check it, but when you create animals in the bracket you dont need to ask them again, you can set their location upon creation ,

Comment: OK.  I will play around with it some and see if I get it right.  Thanks again.

Comment: The animals in the above update will move to an open patch but that open patch could be inside another animal's territory, right?  Can the animal move to an open patch that is outside all other animal territories, so that its territory is mostly separated from the others?

Comment: for example you can do it this way :   move-to one-of patches with [not any? animals in-radius 5]
      set territory pathces-in-territory patch-here 2

Comment: you can also assign a property to each patch so when they are assigned as territory to animals their value will be false so next time you need to place the turtle in patches with true value which shows they are available :)