# NetLogo Create turtle at regular distance from each other

Tags: netlogo

I would Like to create turtle at regular distance from each other (and be able to change this distance). I have no ideas how can I do that...
someone can give me a hand?

Comment: You mean like a grid or lattice, or you mean like a random arrangement with a certain minimum distance, or what, exactly? Maybe show us a picture of what you want?

Comment: Maybe this question helps you too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831832/define-home-area-turtles

Comment: thank you both ! and thank's Marzy it's what I whant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean a random arrangement with a certain minimum distance which you can change the distance via a slider or via another parameter you can do as follows:

First create a slider and name it "Min-Distacne" and change the min value to 1 and max to 10 (just an example) and increment by 1 . For example in a 50*50 world size 170 turtles look like this with min distance of 3 patches:

```
  create-turtles 170 [

    Set shape "person"
    move-to one-of patches with [not any? other turtles in-radius Min-Distacne]
  ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With Marzy's answer, all the turtles end up on patch centers. That might actually be what you want! But if you want to allow the turtles to end up on arbitrary points, you might try:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 170 [
    while [any? other turtles in-radius 3] [
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    ]
  ]
end
```

[image]