# How to spawn turtles a certain amount of patches away from each other

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to spawn turtles 5 patches away from each other but I'm not sure how, right now they all spawn on green patches (I don't want them to spawn on brown ones) and I'm not sure how exactly you control the distance between the spawning of turtles, thanks.

```
breed [ humans person ]
breed [ zombies zombie ]

to setup_world
  clear-all
  reset-ticks

    ask patches [
    set pcolor green
  ]

  ask n-of 100 patches [ 
    set pcolor brown 
  ]

  ask n-of 15 patches with [pcolor != brown][sprout-humans 1 [set size 5
    set color blue
    set shape "person"]]

    ask n-of 5 patches with [pcolor != brown][sprout-zombies 1 [set size 4
    set color red
    set shape "person"]]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this question: [NetLogo Create turtle at regular distance from each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954252/netlogo-create-turtle-at-regular-distance-from-each-other)?

Anyway, I thought that showing you some working functions would be helpful, here I made two alternatives, `sprout-distanced1` and `sprout-distanced2`, you can test them both by alternating which line is commented; I also added a slider called `Min-Distance` to control the turtles spacing.

- `sprout-distanced1` uses the keyword `carefully` with is basically a try-else block, it's there in case that the turtle doesn't find a patch distanced enough to move to, in which case rather than sending a warning the turtle will stay where it is and print its distance to the closest turtle.
- `sprout-distanced2` uses a while loop, in case that the turtle doesn't find a place to move to that is at least `Min-Distance` from another turtle it will reduce the minimum radius by a small amount until it can distance itself from other turtles, if it had to move to a patch where it is less than `Min-Distance` away from other turtles it will log the distance at the `Command Center`.

```
breed [ humans person ]
breed [ zombies zombie ]

to setup_world
  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  ask patches
  [
    set pcolor green
  ]

  ask n-of 100 patches
  [ 
    set pcolor brown 
  ]

  ask n-of 15 patches with [pcolor != brown]
  [
    sprout-humans 1
    [
      set size 5
      set color blue
      set shape "person"
      ;sprout-distanced1
      sprout-distanced2
    ]
  ]

  ask n-of 5 patches with [pcolor != brown]
  [
    sprout-zombies 1
    [
      set size 4
      set color red
      set shape "person"
      ;sprout-distanced1
      sprout-distanced2
    ]
  ]
end

to sprout-distanced1
  
  carefully
  [
    ; try to move at least Min-Distance away from other turtles
    move-to one-of patches with [not any? other turtles in-radius Min-Distance]
  ]
  [
    ; if can't move Min-Distance away from other turtles
    ; stay put and log the min distance to other turtle, just for reference
    show distance min-one-of other turtles [distance myself]
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    sprout-distanced1
  ]
end


to sprout-distanced2
  
  let min-dist Min-Distance
  let moved? FALSE
  
  while [not moved? and min-dist > 0]
  [
    ; can distance it self somewhere?
    ifelse any? patches with [not any? other turtles in-radius min-dist]
    [
      ; if yes, go there
      move-to one-of patches with [not any? other turtles in-radius min-dist]
      set moved? TRUE
      ; if had to reduce the distancing radious log it
      if moved? and min-dist < Min-Distance
      [
        show distance min-one-of other turtles [distance myself]
      ]
    ]
    [
      ; no where to go, reduce the distancing radious
      set min-dist min-dist - 0.1
    ]
  ]
  
end
```

Choose whichever suits better your model.