# Agent that act (change a value of one variable) on patches where it is not above

Tags: patch, agent, netlogo

How can I write a code that permit to an agent to change a value of a variables of a patches,where the agent is not above? It is the case of a farmer, in a previous question I asked how to create the farm. Is it possible that an agent could change a variable of different patches during the same tick? thank you very much for your help.

After 1 tick

[image]

After 30 tick

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is related to your [Farmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173909/netlogo-creation-of-a-cluster-as-a-farm-manage-by-a-turtle/21300846?noredirect=1#comment32196983_21300846) question you can use following:

When you want to make  changes on a group of patches with a common property you should filter them with their common property , for example if the belong so same Farmer just `ask Farm` if you want to make changes on a patches from a farm which has food = 1 you can ask

```
ask farm with [food = 1]
```

In summary, I think you should include these kind of condition in your cultivate procedure to filter which patch is being changed.

```
ask farm with [land-sustainability < 2.1 or water-level = 1]
[
 set food 1 
 set pcolor green
]

ask farm with [The condition which they should set fuel to 1]
[
set fuel 1
set pcolor red
 ]
```

**UPDATE**

```
turtles-own  [
   profit-from-fuel
   profit-from-food
   expected-fuel-sell-price
   expected-food-sell-price
   profit
   farm
   farm-size
   ;risk-attitude-food
   ;risk-attitude-fuel
 ]


patches-own  [
  fuel-yeld
  food-yeld
  land-sustainability
  water-level
  belongs-to
  food
  fuel

 ]

globals      [
  fuel-sell-price
  food-sell-price
  governs        
   ]


to setup        
 clear-all
 clear-all-plots
 create-farmers
 setup-land
 reset-ticks

  ask turtles
     [     set-farm-in-radius farm-size   ]

set fuel-sell-price 30 ;+ random 2 + random -2 
set food-sell-price 30 ;+ random 2 + random -2 

end


to create-farmers


create-turtles 30

[
 set shape "person"
 setxy random-pxcor random-pycor 
 set profit-from-fuel  0  ; indicizzazione del profitto iniziale a 0
 set profit-from-food 0  ; indicizzazione del profitto iniziale a 0 

 set farm-size random 5 + 1
 set label farm-size
 ]
 end


 to setup-land

 ask patches [set belongs-to nobody]

 ask patches
  [

   set pcolor 3
   set food-yeld 10000 
   set fuel-yeld 10000
   set land-sustainability random 5
   set water-level random 3
    ]

  end


to set-farm-in-radius [d]
 move-to one-of patches with [not any? other patches in-radius d with [belongs-to !=    nobody]]
 set farm patches in-radius farm-size
 ask farm [set belongs-to myself]
 let c random 6 + 61
 ask farm [set pcolor c]
 end


to set-farm-distance [d]
  move-to one-of patches with [not any? other patches with [belongs-to != nobody and   distance myself < d]]
  set farm patches with [distance myself < d] 
  ask farm [set belongs-to myself]
  let c random 6 + 61
  ask farm [set pcolor c]
end



to go

  tick

   ask turtles [

  set expected-fuel-sell-price fuel-sell-price + random 5 + random -5           
  if expected-fuel-sell-price < 0 [set expected-fuel-sell-price 1]
  set expected-food-sell-price food-sell-price  + random 5 + random -5
  if expected-food-sell-price < 0 [set expected-food-sell-price 1]
  set profit profit-from-fuel + profit-from-food
  if profit = 0 [ set profit 1 ]
  ]


  set fuel-sell-price fuel-sell-price + random 5 + random -5 
  if fuel-sell-price < 0 or fuel-sell-price = 0 [set fuel-sell-price 1 ]     
  set food-sell-price food-sell-price + random 5 + random -5  
  if food-sell-price < 0 or food-sell-price = 0 [set food-sell-price 1]       



  ask turtles [ 

     cultivate
ask farm [recolor-farm]
     set profit profit-from-food + profit-from-fuel
    ;if water-level > 0.95 [ set profit profit - (profit * ( 2 / profit ))  ] valutare se inserire anche una failing probability
     ]




 if ticks =  Duration [ stop ] 
 if ticks > Duration [stop]

end

to cultivate

  ifelse land-sustainability < 2.1 or water-level = 1
  [

    set profit-from-food  food-sell-price * (((food-yeld ) ^ (1 - alfa)) * (((water-level) ^ (1 - gamma)) * ((land-sustainability) ^ (gamma)) ^ alfa)) 

    ask farm with [land-sustainability < 2.1 or water-level = 1] 
    [
      set food 1 

    ]


  ]

  [
    let utility-from-food ((food-yeld * expected-food-sell-price * land-sustainability) ^ risk-attitude ) / risk-attitude 
    let utility-from-fuel ((food-yeld * expected-fuel-sell-price * land-sustainability) ^ (1 - risk-attitude) ) / ( 1 - risk-attitude)


    ifelse utility-from-food < utility-from-fuel
    [

      set profit-from-fuel fuel-sell-price * (((fuel-yeld ) ^ (1 - alfa)) * (((water-level) ^ (1 - gamma)) * ((land-sustainability) ^ (gamma)) ^ alfa)) 

      ask farm with [land-sustainability >= 2.1 or water-level != 1][
        set fuel 1 


      ]
    ]
    [

      set profit-from-food food-sell-price * (((food-yeld ) ^ (1 - alfa)) * (((water-level) ^ (1 - gamma)) * ((land-sustainability) ^ (gamma)) ^ alfa)) 

      ask farm with [land-sustainability >= 2.1 or water-level != 1] [
        set food 1

      ]

    ]
  ]



end

to recolor-farm
      if food = 1 [set pcolor green ]
      if fuel = 1 [set pcolor red]
end
```

[image]

Comment: ok but the second condition is an evaluation based on patch variable and turtle variable. In particular the variable utility-from-fuel and utility-from-food are created by two report, but I don't if they are correct or not. I copied the two report in the original post. In particular if utility-from-fuel < utility-from-food,but if I write this condition I get a run time error "this code can't be run by a patch
error while turtle 14 running UTILITY-FROM-FOOD"..

Comment: One way to use turtle  variable in patch context is to store the value in temporary local  variable and then use the value in your patch for example before ask farm use : let f1 utility-from-fuel and let f2 utility-from-food and then use if f1 < f2

Comment: I think the problem is in the report function when the model calculate the utility from food and from fuel, this value is defined with expected price that is a turtle-own variable. But I don't know how to handle that.

Comment: You store that price in a local variable and then use it in your condition

Comment: If you still have questions , please ask a new question with detailed explanation of your current problem :)

Comment: Thank you very much Marzy!I've only one question, at the end of the first tick I expcted all the patches colored with red or green, it means they were used to cultivate, but in the model there are patches where food and fuel are = 0, why?

Comment: maybe you should check if they fit into any conditions, see what they have in common and try to change the condition to include them as well

Comment: Can you paste the whole code I've ran the code but the colors of the patches after the first tick don't changa as you can see in the post.Thank you very much, I hope to not bother you again :-)

Comment: I saw but I tried again but after the first tick the colors of patches don't change. I tried copying all the code, but the problem still remaian, have you an idea why? I run the netlogo version 5.0.4

Comment: What about alfa 0.2 , gamma 0.4, risk factor 0.5, ?

Comment: Now It works!! I've specified in the recolor function if fuel = 0 and food = 1 set pcolor green and if fuel = 1 and food = 0 set pcolor red. At the end of the go procedure I've put this code to "clean" the value of all patches: ask patches [set food 0 set fuel 0]. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It is a special feature of NetLogo that an agent can directly change the value of a variable of the patch it is directly over (i.e., `ask turtle 0 [ set pcolor blue ]` will turn the patch under `turtle 0` to `blue`), but any turtle can `ask` any patch to change one of its variables.

For example:

```
ask turtles [
  ask patch-ahead 1 [
    set pcolor green
  ]
]
```

will tell all turtles to change to color of the patch ahead of them (not directly under) to `green`.

They can also ask multiple patches to do stuff, like in the [`in-radius`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#in-radius) example found in the user manual:

```
ask turtles [
  ask patches in-radius 3 [
    set pcolor red
  ]
]
```

Comment: In my case I have this problem, the turtles decide wheter cultivate for producing food or fuel. The decision is taken with evaluating the land condition (patches-own variables) and risk-attittude (turtles -own). From this evaluation the turtles would decide if use a land (a single patches of his farm) for producing fuel or food; unfortunately after several attempts the models change only the color of the patches where there is the turtle or change with the same color the entire patches that represent the farm.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way that you can do it:

```
  turtles-own  [
   profit-from-fuel
   profit-from-food
   expected-fuel-sell-price
   expected-food-sell-price
   profit
   farm
   farm-size
   ;risk-attitude-food
   ;risk-attitude-fuel
 ]


patches-own  [
  fuel-yeld
  food-yeld
  land-sustainability
  water-level
  belongs-to
  food
  fuel

 ]

globals      [
  fuel-sell-price
  food-sell-price
  governs        
   ]


to setup        
 clear-all
 clear-all-plots
 create-farmers
 setup-land
 reset-ticks

  ask turtles
     [     set-farm-in-radius farm-size   ]

set fuel-sell-price 30 ;+ random 2 + random -2 
set food-sell-price 30 ;+ random 2 + random -2 

end


to create-farmers


create-turtles 30

[
 set shape "person"
 setxy random-pxcor random-pycor 
 set profit-from-fuel  0  ; indicizzazione del profitto iniziale a 0
 set profit-from-food 0  ; indicizzazione del profitto iniziale a 0 

 set farm-size random 5 + 1
 set label farm-size
 ]
 end


 to setup-land

 ask patches [set belongs-to nobody]

 ask patches
  [

   set pcolor 3
   set food-yeld 10000 
   set fuel-yeld 10000
   set land-sustainability random 5
   set water-level random 3
    ]

  end


to set-farm-in-radius [d]
 move-to one-of patches with [not any? other patches in-radius d with [belongs-to !=    nobody]]
 set farm patches in-radius farm-size
 ask farm [set belongs-to myself]
 let c random 6 + 61
 ask farm [set pcolor c]
 end


to set-farm-distance [d]
  move-to one-of patches with [not any? other patches with [belongs-to != nobody and   distance myself < d]]
  set farm patches with [distance myself < d] 
  ask farm [set belongs-to myself]
  let c random 6 + 61
  ask farm [set pcolor c]
end



to go

  tick

   ask turtles [

  set expected-fuel-sell-price fuel-sell-price + random 5 + random -5           
  if expected-fuel-sell-price < 0 [set expected-fuel-sell-price 1]
  set expected-food-sell-price food-sell-price  + random 5 + random -5
  if expected-food-sell-price < 0 [set expected-food-sell-price 1]
  set profit profit-from-fuel + profit-from-food
  if profit = 0 [ set profit 1 ]
  ]


  set fuel-sell-price fuel-sell-price + random 5 + random -5 
  if fuel-sell-price < 0 or fuel-sell-price = 0 [set fuel-sell-price 1 ]     
  set food-sell-price food-sell-price + random 5 + random -5  
  if food-sell-price < 0 or food-sell-price = 0 [set food-sell-price 1]       



  ask turtles [ 

     cultivate
ask farm [recolor-farm]
     set profit profit-from-food + profit-from-fuel
    ;if water-level > 0.95 [ set profit profit - (profit * ( 2 / profit ))  ] valutare se inserire anche una failing probability
     ]




 if ticks =  Duration [ stop ] 
 if ticks > Duration [stop]

end

to cultivate
  let r risk-attitude 
  let e-f expected-fuel-sell-price
  let e-food expected-food-sell-price

  ask farm [
    ifelse land-sustainability < 2.1 or water-level = 1
    [ ask myself [set profit-from-food  food-sell-price * (((sum [food-yeld] of farm  ) ^ (1 - alfa)) * (((water-level) ^ (1 - gamma)) * ((land-sustainability) ^ (gamma)) ^ alfa)) 
      ]set food 1 

    ]

    [

      if land-sustainability >= 2.1 or water-level  = 0
      [

        let utility-from-food (( food-yeld  * e-food * land-sustainability) ^ r ) / r
        let utility-from-fuel (( fuel-yeld  * e-f * land-sustainability) ^ (1 - r) ) / ( 1 - r)


        ifelse utility-from-food < utility-from-fuel
        [
          ask myself [set profit-from-fuel fuel-sell-price * (((fuel-yeld ) ^ (1 - alfa)) * (((water-level) ^ (1 - gamma)) * ((land-sustainability) ^ (gamma)) ^ alfa)) ]
          set fuel 1 
        ]
        [ ask myself [set profit-from-food food-sell-price * (((food-yeld ) ^ (1 - alfa)) * (((water-level) ^ (1 - gamma)) * ((land-sustainability) ^ (gamma)) ^ alfa)) ]
          set food 1

        ]

      ]
    ]


  ]
end

to recolor-farm
      if food = 1 [set pcolor green ]
      if fuel = 1 [set pcolor red]
end
```

and this is after first tick:

[image]

This is final view:

[image]

Comment: Please check the conditions for water level and any other criteria that you might have in mind. Regards. Marzy